# How to redraw open layers map when div tag drag?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

In my html page I have 2 panels. Left panel contains map and right panel contains table data. Map should redraw/added more cities when panel drag.
I am able to populate map into left panel but not able to make large map when panel drag. I am also using ignite UI nested Splitter to split map and table into one HTML page. Here is fiddle to work on: https://jsfiddle.net/nparikh/g21uvqt9/3/
Here is IgniteUI for reference`https://www.igniteui.com/splitter/nested-splitters`

Comment: Please clarify your **question**

Comment: You need an event when panel drag and wrap `map.updateSize();` within the event function

Comment: I modified question. Please look into this. I also added reference of Igniteui UI how I want. And my Fiddle is also here

Comment: I found solution using this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/T4St6/82/.